# How to include a SQL Server CE database file in appdata folder using wix installer

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, sql-server-ce

I have created a Windows application in which I have used a SQL Server CE database. Further, I have used Wix installer to create installer for this application.

After installing application, when I run application as administrator, everything is fine.

But when I run application without administrator privileges, I get an exception:

> Access to the database file is not allowed

I want to know the procedure to add the `.sdf` file into Wix installer so that it creates a separate folder below the `AppData` folder, and places the `.sdf` file there.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Consider creating the file in code, either by embedding as resource or just create using SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase

Comment: I followed this procedure, and it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating the file in code, either by embedding as resource or just create using SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase